# Find 99% confidence interval

Tags: statistics

Can anyone help in these questions?

The Government is interested in knowing the average  gas consumption of a typical family. One hundred houses are chosen and asked to measure the gas consumption for 8 hours.The average gas consumption of the 100 houses is $ 30m^3/h $ with a Standard deviation of $ 6.2m^3/h $.

a) I need to find the Find the 99% confidence interval for the average gas consumption in a typical house.

So I did:

n=100

$ \mu =30 $

Standard deviation=6.2

It will be :

$\bar X $ $ ~N (30,\frac{6.2}{100}) $ then,

99% CI = $\bar x $ $ \pm 2.576. \frac{6.2}{\sqrt(100)} $

99% CI = $30 \pm 1.597 $=(28.403,31.6)

Can anyone let me know if the interval is correct or if I am doing anything wrong.

b) If we don't want that the length of the confidence interval should not be greater than  $ 1m^3/h $, what is the minimum number of houses required to do the test? If it is not possible to add more houses to the test , how confident would you be about a CI with length  $ 1m^3/h $ ?

I am not sure how to start this question, I am not sure if the  $ 1m^3/h $ correspondes to 1%=0.001 and in this case I think I need to do :

p=0.062

$ 0.001=  \sqrt( \frac{0.062.(1-0.062)}{100} ) = \frac{0.24}{10} = 0.024 $
so n=0.024

But I am not sure if my approach to this problem is correct.

For the question how confident would you be about a CI with length  $ 1m^3/h $ ?
 I really appreciate a clue.

thanks

Comment: You should be taking the square root of the $6.2$ when you compute the CI (based on the standard deviation, not the variance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your 99% CI $(28.403,\,31.6)$ is pretty good.
I might refine it as $30 \pm 2.576(0.62)$ or $(28.403, 31.597)$.
The usual rule is to use one more decimal place in the CI than in the data,
so maybe $(28.40, 31.60).$

From Minitab statistical software:

```
 MTB > OneZ 100 30;
 SUBC>   Sigma 6.2;
 SUBC>   Confidence 99.

 One-Sample Z 

 The assumed standard deviation = 6.2

   N    Mean  SE Mean       99% CI
 100  30.000    0.620  (28.403, 31.597)
```

Note: I assumed that the $population$ SD is $\sigma = 6.2$ and
used Minitab's Z-interval procedure. If it's really
the $sample$ SD, that's $S = 6.2,$ and the answer from
Minitab's t-interval procedure will be almost exactly
the same because the sample size $n = 100$ is so large.

For the second part, you need the margin of error to be
$E = q(SE) = q(.62) = .5$, so $q = .5/.62 = 0.8065.$ ($E = .5$ means
that the confidence interval $\bar X \pm E$ will be one unit long.)
The area under the normal curve between $\pm 0.8054$ is about $0.58.$
So you could have "58% confidence" in the confidence interval
$30 \pm .5$ or $(29.5, 30.5)$ of length $1.0.$

Minitab again (to check):

```
 MTB > OneZ 100 30;
 SUBC>   Sigma 6.2;
 SUBC>   Confidence 58.

 One-Sample Z 

 The assumed standard deviation = 6.2

   N    Mean  SE Mean       58% CI
 100  30.000    0.620  (29.500, 30.500)
```

> In dealing with confidence intervals three goals are in
>   tension: (a) small $n$, (b) short interval, (c) high confidence.
>   For the same situation, any "improvement" in one of the three
>   must lead to a less desirable value of one or both of the others.
>   Here, we regard $n = 100$ as fixed, so there is a compromise
>   between a short interval and a high confidence.
>   The original 99% CI gave an interval about 3.2 units long.
>   If we insist on a CI only 1.0 unit long, then the confidence
>   level plunges to 58%.

If you want a 99% CI of length 1, then you need to increase
the sample size $n$. Some books give a formula for finding
the required $n$. In this situation, the formula gives
$n \approx = [2.576*\sigma/E]^2 = [(2.576)(6.2)/.5]^2 = 1020.317,$ By custom,
this would be rounded $up$ to $n = 1021$. I will leave it
to you to find and/or prove this formula, which is based
on finding $n$ so that the margin of error is $2.576\sigma/\sqrt{n} = .5$

Minitab once more:

```
 MTB > OneZ 1021 30;
 SUBC>   Sigma 6.2;
 SUBC>   Confidence 99.

 One-Sample Z 

 The assumed standard deviation = 6.2

    N    Mean  SE Mean       99% CI
 1021  30.000    0.194  (29.500, 30.500)
```

Comment: I am trying to understand how  you calculated the margin error because I saw a formula to calculate the Margin Error for a sample proportion, $ z* . \sqrt \frac {p.(1-p)}{n} $ where z*=2.576 ,I think p is 0.62 because it is $  \frac{S.D}{n} $ = $ \frac{6.2}{10}=0.62 $ so, $ 2.576 . \sqrt \frac {0.62.(1-0.62)}{100} $ which give a margin of error of 0.13.

Comment: The confidence interval under the curve between $ \pm 0.13 $  is 0.55-0.448=0.102 which is $ (30 \pm 0.13 )$  .To find n we can use  $ n= ( \frac{z*.S.D}{SE} )^2 $ so $ n=  ( \frac{2.576*6.2}{0.} )^2=15093.45 $ But I know that is wrong comparing it to your results and Minitab. Can you explain me how did you calculate? thanks for your help

Comment: Formula for a 99% z-confidence interval as in one of your orig'l equations: $\bar X \pm 2.576(6.2/\sqrt{100}).$ Formulas in your first comment just above appear to be using a standard error from a $binomial$ confidence interval (for a success probability); not applicable here. In the 2nd comment you seem to confuse SD with SE or SE with margin of error E. In your problem: SD = 6.2, $SE = SD/\sqrt{n}$. CI is $\bar X \pm E.$ Hope that helps.

Comment: Formula for a 99% z-confidence interval as in one of your orig'l equations: $\bar X ±2.576(6.2/\sqrt{100})$. Formulas in your first comment just above appear to be using a standard error from a $binomia$l confidence interval (for a success probability); not applicable here. In the 2nd comment you seem to confuse $SD = \sigma$ with SE or SE with margin of error E. In your problem: $SD = \sigma = 6.2$, $SE= SD/\sqrt{n}$. CI is $\bar X \pm E.$ Hope that helps. (I have also edited my answer to make the notation a little more complete.)

Comment: I was checking my previous answer and I did a couple of mistakes but now I understood everything. I was confused because I did not know the meaning of 'q' but I understood how to find it. I have one more question, Do I need to prove the formula when finding n?

Comment: CIs are important and this problem contains a lot of the crucial fundamentals. A lot to understand. Worth the effort. You should understand proof of formula for $n$. How you present your hwk answers is up to your instructor.